# Compare multiple projection strings to shortlist unique projections

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr, well-known-text

I have a list containing multiple projection strings. Each string is unique but there are some string which are same projections despite being different.

```
[
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_North_Central_FIPS_4202_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",6561666.666666666],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-98.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",32.13333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",33.96666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",31.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_Lambert_Conformal_Conic\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD83_Texas_South_Central\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_2011_UTM_Zone_14N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_NAD_1983_2011\",DATUM[\"D_NAD_1983_2011\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_NSRS2007_StatePlane_Texas_North_Central_FIPS_4202_FtUS\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_NAD_1983_NSRS2007\",DATUM[\"D_NAD_1983_NSRS2007\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",6561666.666666666],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-98.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",32.13333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",33.96666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",31.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",30.28333333333333],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",600000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",4000000.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983_HARN\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983_HARN\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N (Feet Horizontal)\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1640416.666666667],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-93.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988_Foot_US\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"Albers_Conical_Equal_Area\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Albers\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-96.0],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",29.5],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",45.5],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",23.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"TSMS_NAD83\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1000000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",1000000.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",27.41667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",34.91667],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",1.0],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",31.16667],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842499.999999998],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.30480060960121924]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.000,298.25722210]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.000],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.33333333333300],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666666],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.11666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.30480060960122]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",700000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",3000000.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"User_Defined_Unit\",0.3048]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD83_Texas_Central_ft\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_Geographic Coordinate System\",DATUM[\"D_NORTH_AMERICAN_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",1],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",29.66666666666667],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",2296583.333333334],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",9842500],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.30480060960121924]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_2011_UTM_Zone_14N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_NAD_1983_2011\",DATUM[\"D_NAD_1983_2011\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1640416.666666667],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-93.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD83_Texas_Central_ft\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_Geographic Coordinate System\",DATUM[\"D_NORTH_AMERICAN_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",2296583.333333334],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",1.0],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_Lambert_Conformal_Conic\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666666],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAD_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"Unknown VCS from ArcInfo Workstation\",VDATUM[\"Unknown\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1927_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1927\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1927\",SPHEROID[\"Clarke_1866\",6378206.400,294.97869821]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2000000.000],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.000],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.33333333333300],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666666],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.11666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.30480060960122]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_2011_UTM_Zone_14N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_NAD_1983_2011\",DATUM[\"D_NAD_1983_2011\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101004]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-93.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2296583.333333333],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",9842500.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",30.11666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",31.88333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",29.66666666666667],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Foot\",0.3048]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD83_Texas_South_Central\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]",
    "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",1968500.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",13123333.33333333],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",28.38333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",30.28333333333334],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",27.83333333333333],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]],VERTCS[\"NAVD_1988\",VDATUM[\"North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988\"],PARAMETER[\"Vertical_Shift\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Direction\",1.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]"
]
```

I want to get a list out of them that are actually different **projections** from each other. I have developed this code using osr AutoIdentifyEPSG method but it is only shortlisting a couple. Is there a way to compare projections string to check if they correspond to same projection?

```
from osgeo import osr

unique_proj_str  = # same list as above

filtered_proj_list = []
SRID_list = []

for proj_str in unique_proj_str:
    srs = osr.SpatialReference(proj_str)
    if srs.AutoIdentifyEPSG() == 0:  # success
        SRID = srs.GetAuthorityCode(None)
        if SRID not in SRID_list:
            SRID_list.append(SRID)
            filtered_proj_list.append(proj_str)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        filtered_proj_list.append(proj_str)

print(filtered_proj_list)
```

Comment: In addition to checking the EPSG, you could also check the proj4 representation. For me, it shortlists your 40 WKT strings to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, this is a very hard problem with no easy answer, while *we* can see that 2 projections are identical it is very hard to teach a computer program that they are if there are differences in spelling or format of parameter names. Then even if the parameters match there are differences in precision in the parameters themselves.

The [GeoTools docs](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/compare.html) give some more information on how it can be done and why it is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that would help you, but this is one my functions to get the EPSG code, which can then be used to shortlist your WKT strings:

```
import sys
import fnmatch
import warnings
from osgeo import osr

def get_epsg(spatial_ref):
    # type: (osr.SpatialReference) -> int
    """
    Extract EPSG code from osr.SpatialReference object.

    :param spatial_ref: osr.SpatialReference object
    :return: EPSG code
    """
    try:
        spatial_ref.AutoIdentifyEPSG()
        return int(spatial_ref.GetAttrValue('AUTHORITY', 1))
    except RuntimeError:
        print('Could not auto-identify EPSG code! Trying to look it up in the database...')
        try:
            proj_4 = spatial_ref.ExportToProj4()
            pattern = '*' + '*'.join(proj_4.split(' '))
            if 'win' in sys.platform.lower():
                epsg_db = r'c:\Program Files\GDAL\projlib\epsg'
            else:
                epsg_db = r'/usr/share/proj/epsg'
            with open(epsg_db, 'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            results = []
            for l in lines:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(l, pattern):
                    epsg = int(l.split('>')[0].split('<')[-1])
                    results.append(epsg)
            if len(results) > 1:
                warnings.warn('Found more than one match! Choosing the one with the "largest" EPSG code!')
                return sorted(results)[-1]
            return False
        except RuntimeError:
            print('Could not generate a PROJ4 representation!')
            return False

shortlist = set()
for p in projs:
    sr = osr.SpatialReference()
    sr.ImportFromWkt(p)
    if get_epsg(sr):
        shortlist.add(sr.ExportToWkt())
print(len(projs))
print(len(shortlist))
print(shortlist)
```

---

Comment:

I'm really only comparing EPSG codes here, assuming that different EPSG codes represent different coordinate systems. For this, I query the actual epsg database which GDAL uses in case the `AutoIdentifyEPSG()` method does not do the job in the first place. Since they are separated by their different proj4 strings within this database, that conversion needs to be done first.

Probably the code might need a small adjustment for MacOS to provide the correct GDAL installation path.

This exact code example reduced the number of Wkt strings from 40 to 8 (on my Windows system with an old GDAL installation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you develop/comment your answer more? Is this the same function that shortlisted from 8 to 40. What are we using to compare proj4 representation? I am on OS system.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Do you know if proj4 components are always in order? if not I think doing a list subset would be better then fnmatch ?

Comment: Aslo, is there a similar database to compare ESRI srss proj4

Comment: This is not working the fnmatch never match anything. I checked this by adding a print statement inside if condition.

Comment: Did you make sure the path to the epsg database was correct for your system? Maybe your GDAL installation is newer and the database is built differently. Can only tell you from the perspective of my own system that it works as posted.